# Issue in adding/displaying multi-dimensional char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having difficulty in adding and displaying values in multi-dimensional char array. I am accepting number of days and  various expense amount from the user and wish to add them in my char array..
Something like this `dayWise[day_1][total_expense_on_that_day];`

Here is the code I wrote, kindly tell me where I went wrong.

```
char dayWise[days_count][opening_bal_bk][15]; // Multidimensional array
printf("\nNumber of Days: %d\n", days_count);

for(i = 1; i <= days_count; i++) {
    printf("\n\t");

    printf("\nOpening Balance for Day %d is: %d", i, opening_bal_bk);
    printf("\n\t");

    printf("Day %d \n\t", i);
    printf("---------------");

    printf("\n\tFood: ");
    food_amount = num_valid();

    while(food_amount > opening_bal_bk) {
        printf("Food amount exceeding balance,enter again!");
        printf("\n\tFood: ");
        food_amount = num_valid();
    }
    opening_bal_bk -= food_amount;

    printf("\n\tTravel: ");
    travel_amount = num_valid();
    while(travel_amount > opening_bal_bk) {
        printf("Travel amount exceeding balance,enter again!");
        printf("\n\tTravel: ");
        travel_amount = num_valid();
    }
    opening_bal_bk -= travel_amount;



    dayWise[i][opening_bal_bk]; //adding to array here
```

Comment: To begin with, do not access (no read nor write) out-of-range of array. Array index starts from 0 in C and you mustn't access `dayWise[days_count]` when there are only `days_count` elements in `dayWise`.

Comment: That code does not use the array in any way. `dayWise[i][opening_bal_bk]` does nothing. What are you trying to do with the array?

Comment: I want to add daywise expense in array dayWise. Where 'i' is for which day it is (1,2,3 or so on) and 'opening_bal_bk' is the total amount on that particular day.

Comment: If you just need one balance per day, a single-dimension array would do. As @MarkusLaire said, you're doing nothing there and the correct way would be dayWise[i] += opening_bal_bk; First of all, you need to review your understanding of arrays (single or multi), when they are needed, and how to manipulate their contents.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response. My understanding of multidimensional char array was wrong. I managed to solve this issue :)